# on load first division should be open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want when the page loads the first division should be opened by default.also user preference will be taken if user wants to open the first accordion division then on load of a page the first div will be opened,if the users wants to change the preference to second division then second division will open

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="accordion1">
        <li>
             <h2 id="first">CMT</h2>

            <div class="content">
                <ul class="accord">
                    <li> <a href="#">main link1</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Two</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Three</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Four</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Five</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">main link2</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Two</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Three</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Four</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Five</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h2>FOIS</h2>

            <div class="content">content fois</div>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h2>ASP</h2>

            <div class="content">content ASP</div>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h2>PTT</h2>

            <div class="content">content PTT</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
.accordion1 {
    width: 178px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.accordion1 h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
    color: #333;
    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_gray.gif') repeat-x;
    background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion1 h2:hover {
    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
    color: white;
}
.accordion1 li div.content {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #fcfbfb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
}
.accordion1 li:hover h2 {
    color: white;
    background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
}
.accord > li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.accord > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    color: #5f5c5c;
    background: url("./compo_images/arrow_pointer_se.gif") 0.002em no-repeat;
}
.accord > li > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5f5c5c;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: url("./compo_images/arrow_dirmini_orange_e.gif") 0.35em no-repeat;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
.accord > li > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px;
}
.accord {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.accord > li > a:hover {
    color: #f8b106;
}
.accord > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #f8b106;
}

.accordion1 > li > h2.active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {


    var $lis = $('.accordion1 > li'), $contents = $lis.children('.content').hide();
    var $h2s = $lis.children('h2').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this), $t = $this.next();
        $contents.not($t).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $this.toggleClass('active', !$t.is(':visible'));
        $t.slideToggle();
        $h2s.not(this).removeClass('active');
    })
})
```

js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dh7Cc/2/

Comment: *sidenote:* 0 has no unit in CSS. no need to add `px` after `0`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor ok i will take care :D

Comment: Maybe you can add unique id to each element in your accordeon. Then just apply .show() to the element you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger a click event on the first `h2` element

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $lis = $('.accordion1 > li'), $contents = $lis.children('.content').hide();
    var $h2s = $lis.children('h2').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this), $t = $this.next();
        $contents.not($t).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $this.toggleClass('active', !$t.is(':visible'));
        $t.slideToggle();
        $h2s.not(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $h2s.first().click()
})
```

Comment: suppose each h2 element has a unique id .so i want the division opened on the id basis

Comment: @user2841408 then `$('#first').click()`

Comment: @user2841408 instead of `$h2s.first().click()`